# How do I get the name of the rows from the index of a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a data frame with row names that aren't a column of their own per se, such as the following:

```
        X  Y
 Row 1  0  5
 Row 2  8  1
 Row 3  3  0
```

How would I extract the name of these rows as a list, if I have their index?
For example, it would look something like:

```
function_name(dataframe[indices])
> ['Row 1', 'Row 2']
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`df.index`

- outputs the row names as pandas `Index` object.

`list(df.index)`

- casts to a list.

`df.index['Row 2':'Row 5']`

- supports label slicing similar to columns.

Answer (score 6):

this seems to work fine :

```
dataframe.axes[0].tolist()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pull out only the index values for certain integer-based row-indices, you can do something like the following using the `iloc` method:

```
In [28]: temp
Out[28]:
       index                 time  complete
row_0      2  2014-10-22 01:00:00         0
row_1      3  2014-10-23 14:00:00         0
row_2      4  2014-10-26 08:00:00         0
row_3      5  2014-10-26 10:00:00         0
row_4      6  2014-10-26 11:00:00         0

In [29]: temp.iloc[[0,1,4]].index
Out[29]: Index([u'row_0', u'row_1', u'row_4'], dtype='object')

In [30]: temp.iloc[[0,1,4]].index.tolist()
Out[30]: ['row_0', 'row_1', 'row_4']
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want to get the index values, you can simply do:

> dataframe.index

this will output a pandas.core.index

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
df.index.to_list()
```

Answer (score -2):

we're assuming:

```
type(data)= pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

then we want to find out the row's numbers:

```
data= data.shape[0]
```